# Django : custom management command not registered using app config

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to build some custom commands for one of my Django app. I followed the documentation and put the code of my command inside a file, with this folder structure :

```
|--myproject   
   |--myapp
      |--management
         |--commands
            |--__init__.py
            |--index.py
         |--__init__.py
      |--__init__.py
      |--apps.py
      |--...
   |--otherapp
      |--management
         |--commands
            |--__init__.py
            |--delete.py
         |--__init__.py
      |--__init__.py
      |--..
   |--...
|--manage.py
```

I need to have an apps.py file because I'm using signals in this app. Thus, my **init**.py file in myapp folder is:

```
default_app_config = 'myproject.myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

and the apps.py file is:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        import myproject.myapp.signals
```

Then, once I run the server, I try to call my custom command, but it is not registered. I tried to call

```
python manage.py
```

and the command was not present.

After that, I tried to do the same, but I only changed my **init**.py file by making it empty. Thus, my app use the default AppConfig. And it worked, my command was available with manage.py. But I can't use signals anymore.

So, my question is, how can register custom commands inside an app if I'm not using the default app config but a custom one?

Thanks

Comment: I tried to reproduce the behavior. But I got the correct output

Comment: Can you explain how can I reproduce the error or can you share your project?

Comment: I edited my post to give a bigger overview of the structure of my project. For instance, in the other app that I have, since there is no apps.py, the custom command is well registered

Comment: Make sure you don't reuse the same `name` or `app_label` in two different apps.

Answer (score 0):

The `AppConfig.name` attribute needs to contain full path of the app.

Your `default_app_config` starts with `myproject.myapp.`, so `AppConfig.name` should be `myproject.myapp`.